# Obtener valores de select múltiple "indexado"

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

Tengo un formulario que voy construyendo dinámicamente con jQuery, una parte específicamente el usuario va duplicando un `fieldset` que a su vez tiene un `select multiple` con el que a su vez se va construyendo otro grupo de campos. Cada uno de estos `select multiple` los tengo con el nombre `adviser[1]`, `adviser[2]`, `adviser[n]` según se van generando...

Pero a la hora de hacer la captura de los datos no funciona como espero, sin embargo si le quito el índice `[1]` si funciona. Pero necesito diferenciar cada uno de los valores a qué índice pertenece.

Adjunto una imagen de lo que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con Laravel, y al imprimir los datos en la pantalla con `dd( $model['adviser'] );` obtengo:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => "4"
  2 => "6"
]
```

Pero si le quito el indice al campo `adviser` me recoge todo el array.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si podes, manda el fragmente del HTML, del JS, y del controlador de PHP.

Comment: Gracias, decidí crear un `json` y enviarlo desde el formulario hacia la base de datos, lo que ahora tengo otro problema -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317069/construir-json-a-medida-que-se-van-agregando-campos-y-valores-a-un-formulario