# Construir JSON a medida que se van agregando campos y valores a un formulario

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un formulario al que voy agregando campos que dependen de un select múltiple, y a la hora de agregar los valores a estos nuevos campos generados necesito ir construyendo un `json` que es el valor de un campo oculto que es el que pretendo enviar a la base de datos.

El resultado de dicho campo oculto lo voy generando en cada evento `focus` y `blur` en los campos de texto de los que recojo sus valores.

En parte funciona, pero sucede lo siguiente:

1. `focus` -> Verifico si el valor actual existe en la lista, entonces lo elimino
2. `blur` -> Agrego el valor a la lista

Si esto sucede dos veces en el mismo campo, en efecto el paso `1` funciona, pero el `2` me agrega ambos valores a la lista nuevamente, el antiguo y el nuevo. Ya llevo un día en esto y sigo dando vueltas y no encuentro la solución.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
data    = []
result  = []
parents = ["0"]
$(document).on('blur', '.adviser-percent', function(){
item        = $(this)
adviserID   = item.attr('data-adviser-id')
percent     = item.val()
parent      = item.parents('.access-level')
level       = parent.attr('data-level-number')
field       = parent.find('.level-number-id')

if (parents[0] != level){
    parents.fill(parent.attr('data-level-number'))
    data = []
}

result  = [ level ]
pair    = [ adviserID, percent ]

data.push(pair)

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997127/how-to-find-the-duplicates-in-a-javascript-multidimensional-array#answer-20997744
noDupes = data
.map(function (item) {
    return JSON.stringify(item);
})
.reduce(function (out, current) {
    if (out.indexOf(current) === -1) out.push(current);
    return out;
}, [])
.map(function (item) {
    return JSON.parse(item);
});

result.push(noDupes)
field.val(JSON.stringify(result))
})

$(document).on('focus', '.adviser-percent', function(){
item        = $(this)
adviserID   = item.attr('data-adviser-id')
percent     = item.val()
parent      = item.parents('.access-level')
level       = parent.attr('data-level-number')
field       = parent.find('.level-number-id')
fieldVal    = field.val()
array       = ( result[1] == null ) ? [] : result[1]

output      = [ level ]
pair        = [ adviserID, percent ]

var filtered = array.filter(function(value, index, arr){
    return JSON.stringify(value) !== JSON.stringify(pair)
})

output.push(filtered)
field.val(JSON.stringify(output))
})
```

Adjunto una imagen para que se tenga una idea más clara de lo que sucede

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edito:**

No puedo usar la solución de enviar el input con nombre tipo arreglo porque no es un solo juego de inputs, pues tengo `n` niveles que el propio usuario va agregando, y dentro de cada nivel hay asesores que el usuario va agregando también y los campos se generan dinámicamente con jquery. ¿Cómo le digo a cada asesor a qué nivel pertenece?

```
nivel 1
    asesor 1, 5%
    asesor 2, 10%
nivel 2
    asesor 1, 7%
    asesor 2, 15%
    asesor n, 30%
nivel 3
    ...
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No entiendo para qué quieres enviar un json a tu bd. ¿Cuál lenguaje es tu backend?

Comment: PHP, necesito guardar ese campo específicamente como `json`

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es mandar toda la información a tu backend. Y simplemente con json_encode($TU_POST) se codifica a json y lo almacenas en tu bd.

Comment: SI, eso lo intenté, pero el problema es que eso que ves en la imagen animada es solo una parte, en realidad se van agregando niveles, y dentro de cada nivel se agregan estos campos de asesores. Eso que dices lo intenté pero creo que es más organizado si lo hago de esta manera https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316580/obtener-valores-de-select-m%c3%baltiple-indexado

Comment: Te estás complicando demasiado bro, solamente tienes que hacer que el input o el select tenga un nombre de tipo arreglo. Ejemplo <select name="asesores[]" ></select>; desde el backend obtienes ese arreglo y lo parseas. La manera en lo que haces es muy ineficiente. Si necesitas más información haz un matriz de select [][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resuelto, entre otras cosas, era la variable `data` la que estaba dando problemas, pues en cada `focus`, `blur` se adicionaban valores repetidos. Entonces se solucionó en el evento `focus` igualándola a `filtered`

`data = filtered`

Finalmente el código ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

```
data    = []
result  = []
parents = ["0"]

$(document).on('focus', '.adviser-percent', function(){
    item        = $(this)
    adviserID   = item.attr('data-adviser-id')
    percent     = item.val()
    parent      = item.parents('.access-level')
    level       = parent.attr('data-level-number')
    field       = parent.find('.level-data')
    fieldVal    = field.val()

    if ( fieldVal !== '' ){
        array = JSON.parse(fieldVal)[1]
    } else if ( result[1] == null ){
        array = []
    } else {
        array = result[1]
    }

    output      = [ level ]
    pair        = [ adviserID, percent ]

    var filtered = array.filter(function(value, index, arr){
        return JSON.stringify(value) !== JSON.stringify(pair)
    })

    output.push(filtered)
    var newData = data.filter(function(value, index, arr){
        return JSON.stringify(value) !== JSON.stringify(pair)
    })

    data = filtered // 

    field.val(JSON.stringify(output))
})

$(document).on('blur', '.adviser-percent', function(){
    item        = $(this)
    adviserID   = item.attr('data-adviser-id')
    percent     = item.val()
    parent      = item.parents('.access-level')
    level       = parent.attr('data-level-number')
    field       = parent.find('.level-data')
    fieldVal    = field.val()

    if (parent.hasClass('level-real')){
        if (parents[0] != level){
            parents.fill(parent.attr('data-level-number'))
            if (array.length > 0){
                data = array
            } else {
                data = []
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (parents[0] != level){
            parents.fill(parent.attr('data-level-number'))
            data = []
        }
    }

    result  = [ level ]
    pair    = [ adviserID, percent ]

    data.push(pair)

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997127/how-to-find-the-duplicates-in-a-javascript-multidimensional-array#answer-20997744
    noDupes = data
    .map(function (item) {
        return JSON.stringify(item);
    })
    .reduce(function (out, current) {
        if (out.indexOf(current) === -1) out.push(current);
        return out;
    }, [])
    .map(function (item) {
        return JSON.parse(item);
    });

    result.push(noDupes)
    field.val(JSON.stringify(result))
})
```

La imagen grafica el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]